# WriteHTML Function of tcpdf generating error

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

writehtml function is showing me the following error

```
PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in 
F:\XXXXXXXX\libraries\pdf\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 21942
```

My code as follows:

```
$html = covertArrayToString($msg,$array);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html,true,0,true);
```

`$array` has all values populted from DB.
`$msg` is the html template
when I `echo $html`, It show the pdf in html format
but next line I am getting error.

Comment: I have echo $array also and  i am able to get full array,can anyonr help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess the **writehtml** you r using is for [mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=121)

for tcpdf the correct way would be

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

hope it solve your problem.

Comment: Thank for ur post...It really helped.